# Toggle class for CheckBoxes plus validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a LOT of checkboxes, 95. They all have hte same class and are named as an array. I need to change the class from bg-primary to bg-success or some other color. I also need to be able to say at the end, 'You missed this checkbox'. this is where I am at now

```
   <h3 class = "col-lg-12 text-center bg-warning "><a href="#">STEP 5 - Under the hood</a></h3>
    <div id= "acc4">
   <form>
     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="78">Check oil condition and level
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="79">Check coolant condition and level
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="80">Check trans fluid condition and level
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="81">Check power steering fluid condition and level
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="82">Check brake fluid condition and level
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="83">Fill washer fluid resevoir
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="84">Battery hold down
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="85">Check battery &amp; charging system
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-primary">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="86">Inspeect belts
     </fieldset>
```

and the Jquery I am using unsuccessfully is

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('form-horizontal form-group bg-warning',    this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should use the `.closest('fieldset')` since that is where you want to apply the classes.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset')
        .removeClass('bg-primary') // remove the bg-primary once clicked
        .toggleClass('bg-warning', !this.checked) // show warning when un-checked
        .toggleClass('bg-success', this.checked); // show success when checked
});
```

And to find the unchecked ones at the end use

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked') // add .closest('fieldset') if you need to target the containers again
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get parent and `toggle` class `bg-warning`.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-horizontal.form-group').toggleClass('bg-warning', this.checked);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/uwurzg0z/1/)

Comment: Yes sir. that worked well for that part.. Now how do I create an array of the ones missed?

Answer (score 0):

in the end I used add and remove class in order to get better results from Bootstrap. Borrowing from the first answer I used

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
$(this).closest('.form-horizontal.form-group').removeClass('bg-info', this.checked).addClass('bg-success', this.checked);});
```

This gave better color results, but it lost the ability to switch back if the box becomes unchecked.